# In C++, how do I ask the user to input a string, have that string stored, and be able to recall it in any/many functions?

Tags: c++

I want to be able to have the user enter their name, store it and be able to recall it in different functions. This is my first code, first program. I am sure there is an easier way to do this, so if you could offer both an answer to the question and a easier way of accomplishing this task it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void game();
void other();

class NameClass{

    public:
        string name;

};


int main()
{

    int a;
    int age;
    string name;

        cout << "Hello user, what is you name? \n\n";

            /*Not sure if class and operator needs to be here. I was hoping that when the user
              input the stream(their name) it would be stored in the class as well as being able
              to use it in the main function.*/
            NameClass person;
                //This line is here to get name from user.
                getline(cin, name);

        cout << "Well " << name << ", are you having a good day? \n\n";

            cout << "1=Yes 2=No \n\n";


                cin >> a;
                    cout <<"\n";

                        if(a==1){
                            cout << "Well that is good to hear.\n\n";
                        }else{
                            cout << "I am sorry to hear that. I hope things get better for you. \n\n";
                        }
        cout << "Do you want to play a game? \n\n";

            cin >> a;

                if(a==1){
                    game();

                    }else{
                        other();

                        return 0;
                    }


return 0;
}

void game(){


        /*It is in this function that I want the be able to recall the name that the user input in the main function.*/
    cout << "Cool "<< name <<",let get started." << endl;









}

void other(){

    cout << "Well then "<< name <<", lets do something else.";


}
```

Comment: You have two options: *global variable*, or *function parameter*. Search those terms to learn more about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you aren't aware of the [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) concepts.

Do this (make methods part of the class):

```
class NameClass{

public:
    string name;
    void game();
    void other();

};

int main()
{
    ...
    NameClass person;
    getline(cin, person.name);
    ...
}
```

Or this (pass `name` as parameter):

```
int main()
{
    string name;
    ...
    game(name);
}

void game(string name)
{
    cout << "Cool "<< name <<",let get started." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information from one function to another then you use a function parameter (or more than one).

```
void game(string name);

int main()
{
    string name;
    ...
    game(name);
}

void game(string name)
{
    cout << "Cool "<< name <<",let get started." << endl;
}
```

It's a fundamental concept that pretty much all programming languages have.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the name as a parameter in both your functions, it should be something like this:

```
//functions
void game(string name);
void other(string name);
```

In your main function when you call either function just pass the name to it.

```
if(a == 1)
{
   game(name);
}
else
{
   other(name);
}
```